# How to change this mutable-referenced struct's field value?

Tags: rust

In the below code (a small reduced example extracted from my project) I'm trying to change the `condition` in `query_construction` where I have an `condition: Option<&'a mut PlayerConditions>`.

REPL: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/gb7jfn

I cannot understand how to do this, I tried:

```rust
condition = Some(
    &mut condition
        .unwrap_or(&mut PlayerConditions::new())
        .set_email(None),
);
```

but the error is:

```
error[E0384]: cannot assign to immutable argument `condition`
  --> src\main.rs:72:9
   |
59 |           condition: Option<&'a mut PlayerConditions>,
   |           --------- help: consider making this binding mutable: `mut condition`
...
72 | /         condition = Some(
73 | |             &mut condition
74 | |                 .unwrap_or(&mut PlayerConditions::new())
75 | |                 .set_email(None),
76 | |         );
   | |_________^ cannot assign to immutable argument
```

but of course this is not something I want.

I would like to change the value of "mutable-referenced" `condition`.

Is it possible?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct PlayerConditions {
    id: Option<String>,
    name: Option<String>,
    email: Option<String>,
}

impl PlayerConditions {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
    pub fn is_default(&self) -> bool {
        self.id.is_none() && self.name.is_none() && self.email.is_none()
    }
    pub fn id(&self) -> &Option<String> {
        &self.id
    }
    pub fn set_id(mut self, id: Option<String>) -> Self {
        self.id = id;
        self
    }
    pub fn name(&self) -> &Option<String> {
        &self.name
    }
    pub fn set_name(mut self, name: Option<String>) -> Self {
        self.name = name;
        self
    }
    pub fn email(&self) -> &Option<String> {
        &self.email
    }
    pub fn set_email(mut self, email: Option<String>) -> Self {
        self.email = email;
        self
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct PlayerListInput {
    pub condition: Option<PlayerConditions>,
    pub order: Option<String>, // This is not String: is a struct in real code
                               // other fields here...
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DBPlayer {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub email: Option<String>,
}

impl DBPlayer {
    fn query_construction<'a>(
        condition: Option<&'a mut PlayerConditions>,
        order: &Option<String>,
    ) -> String {
        let mut query = "SELECT * FROM players".to_string();

        // --->>> I need to change condition here using this logic:

        // if condition is None add one condition with "set_email(None)"
        // if condition is Some and email == None set "set_email(None)"
        // if condition is Some and email == Some do nothing

        // I tried the below but it doesn't work:

        // condition = Some(
        //     &mut condition
        //         .unwrap_or(&mut PlayerConditions::new())
        //         .set_email(None),
        // );

        // From here it's ok

        if let Some(condition) = condition {
            if !condition.is_default() {
                // query = condition.add_each_one_to(query);
            }
        }

        if let Some(_order) = &order {
            // add order to query
        }

        query.to_string()
    }

    pub async fn query(
        _session: &str, // This is not String: is a struct in real code
        _db: &str,     // This is not String: is a connection/transaction in real code
        input: &mut PlayerListInput,
    ) -> Vec<DBPlayer> {
        // Check session here

        let _query = Self::query_construction(input.condition.as_mut(), &input.order);

        let players = vec![]; // fetch_them_from_db_using_query_here;

        players
    }
}

async fn players_from_repo(input: &mut PlayerListInput) -> Vec<DBPlayer> {
    DBPlayer::query("session", "db_connection", input).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut input = PlayerListInput::default();

    let players = players_from_repo(&mut input).await;

    dbg!(players);
}
```

Comment: Why worry about mutating when you can clone it?

Comment: I don't want clone it because it's very big.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you need to `&mut` this in the first place. Can't you extract the email address itself as a reference, like `if let Some(Some(ref email)) = ...`? I don't see any reason here to have a mutable version if you're adding to a query string. Taking a mutable argument in Rust often complicates things severely as that limits how you can call this.

Comment: PSA: It's often better to return `Option<&T>` than `&Option<T>`, as in `pub fn id(&self) -> Option<&String> { self.id.as_ref() }`. This way you can `unwrap` the returned value without any fuss, and you can trivially unpack it with `let` or `match`.

Comment: I'd also suggest a more Rust-style approach here where you have some kind of `struct` that represents your query builder and it has `impl Display` that can convert it into a string. This way you can compose your query using `write!` internally without concern for manipulating a mutable string buffer. If you have an email condition, just `write!(f, " email=?")` or what have you. I also really hope you're **using placeholder values** here if doing actual SQL, so your return type may need to be more than just `String`.

Comment: @Finomnis, I did. The only external link is a REPL of the below code. All code is in the question.

Comment: Instead of this complicated mess, why won't you use simple `if` statements? It will be easier to see the problem.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what you're referring to?

Comment: `condition = Some(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query_construction function wants an `Option<&mut PlayerConditions>`, when you actually want it to take `&mut Option<PlayerConditions>`.

### what......

`&mut Option<T>` and `Option<&mut T>` are super different, especially when the reference is pointing into a struct field. `&mut Option<T>` means that you can change the value of the Option itself, but not the actual value inside of the option, in order to do that, you have to call `.as_mut()` to get an owned `Option<&mut T>`, which allows you to figure out if you have a reference to T or not.

### why?!?!?!

Because your function wants to modify the `player_conditions`' optionalness, you need a mutable reference to the Option itself, not an optional mutable reference to the player conditions.

With all that in mind, it's now very straightforward to fix your code:

```rust
fn query_construction(
    condition: &mut Option<PlayerConditions>,
    //         ~~~~       ^^ no more &mut
    order: &Option<String>,
) -> String { 
    // ...

    // if condition is None add one condition with "set_email(None)"
    // if condition is Some and email == None set "set_email(None)"
    // if condition is Some and email == Some do nothing

    // note: this satisfies all of the above conditions
    if condition.is_none() {
        *condition = Some(PlayerConditions::new());
    }

    //...
}

pub async fn query(...) -> Vec<DBPlayer> {
    // ...
    
    let _query = Self::query_construction(&mut input.condition, &input.order);
    //                                    ~~~~               ^^ no more .as_mut()

    // ...
}
```