# What pattern or technique can I use in this case?

Tags: rust, design-patterns, builder-pattern

The following code is a small example of what has been bugging my brain for days: [How to change this mutable-referenced struct's field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686358/how-to-change-this-mutable-referenced-structs-field-value).

I'm writing for the first time and by myself a small app that follows the "clean architecture" logic as I have done with other languages (garbage collected).

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong and what better pattern I can use (I'm thinking of a builder pattern, but also various setters methods that allow me to change the values when I need it, in several places)?

The biggest convenience I would like to achieve is to be able to use code like this:

```rust
if let Some(condition) = &mut input.condition {
    condition.set_subscribed_at_is_nil(true);
} else {
    input.condition = Some(PlayerConditions::new().unset_subscribed_at_is_nil());
}
```

or better:

```rust
input.condition.unwrap_or_default().set_subscribed_at_is_nil(true);

// or maybe input.condition = input.condition.unwrap_or_default().set_subscribed_at_is_nil(true);

if something_happened {
    input.condition.unset_it().set_another(Some("something"));
}

if something_else_happened {
    input.condition.set_another(Some("something")).check_something();
}
```

What can you suggest?

The code:

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
*/

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct PlayerConditions {
    id: Option<String>,
    name: Option<String>,
    subscribed_at_is_nil: Option<bool>,
}

impl PlayerConditions {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
    pub fn is_default(&self) -> bool {
        self.id.is_none() && self.name.is_none() && self.subscribed_at_is_nil.is_none()
    }
    pub fn id(&self) -> &Option<String> {
        &self.id
    }
    pub fn set_id(&mut self, id: Option<String>) -> &mut Self {
        self.id = id;
        self
    }
    pub fn name(&self) -> &Option<String> {
        &self.name
    }
    pub fn set_name(&mut self, name: Option<String>) -> &mut Self {
        self.name = name;
        self
    }
    pub fn subscribed_at_is_nil(&self) -> &Option<bool> {
        &self.subscribed_at_is_nil
    }
    pub fn set_subscribed_at_is_nil(&mut self, subscribed_at_is_nil: Option<bool>) -> &mut Self {
        self.subscribed_at_is_nil = subscribed_at_is_nil;
        self
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct PlayerListInput {
    pub condition: Option<PlayerConditions>,
    // This is not String: is a struct in real code
    pub order: Option<String>,
    // other fields here...
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DBPlayer {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: Option<String>,
    // For simplicity this is String in this example
    pub subscribed_at: Option<String>,
}

impl DBPlayer {
    fn query_construction<'a>(
        condition: Option<&'a mut PlayerConditions>,
        order: &Option<String>,
    ) -> String {
        // Sometimes I need to change condition here (so I need the mutability of it)

        let query = "SELECT * FROM players".to_string();

        if let Some(condition) = condition {
            if !condition.is_default() {
                // query = condition.add_each_one_to(query);
            }
        }

        if let Some(_order) = &order {
            // add order to query
        }

        query.to_string()
    }

    pub async fn query(
        _db: &str,      // This is not String: is a connection/transaction in real code
        input: &mut PlayerListInput,
    ) -> Vec<DBPlayer> {
        // Sometimes I need to change input here (so I need the mutability of it)

        let _query = Self::query_construction(input.condition.as_mut(), &input.order);

        let players = vec![]; // fetch_them_from_db_using_query_here;

        players
    }
}

async fn players_from_repo(input: &mut PlayerListInput) -> Vec<DBPlayer> {
    // Here I need to change input checking if something is already added, for example:

    if let Some(condition) = &mut input.condition {
        condition.set_subscribed_at_is_nil(Some(true));
    } else {
        input.condition = Some(PlayerConditions::new().set_subscribed_at_is_nil(Some(true)));
    }

    DBPlayer::query( "db_connection", input).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut input = PlayerListInput::default();

    let players = players_from_repo(&mut input).await;

    // I still need input ownership here
    dbg!(input);

    dbg!(players);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to handle `None` as creating the value and then modifying it the same as if it were `Some`, you'd likely benefit from using one of the [`get_or_insert*`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert) functions on `Option`.

With it, you can write code like this:

```
input.condition
    .get_or_insert_with(PlayerConditions::new)
 // .set_id(None) -- can be chained since your methods take in `&mut Self` and return `&mut Self`
 // .set_name(None)
    .set_subscribed_at_is_nil(Some(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simply:

```rust
if let Some(condition) = &mut input.condition {
    condition.set_subscribed_at_is_nil(Some(true));
} else {
    let mut new_condition = PlayerConditions::new();
    new_condition.set_subscribed_at_is_nil(Some(true));
    input.condition = Some(new_condition);
}
```

Yes, it's a bit longer, but it's crystal clear and we don't always need the shortest code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as always in this case the real code is much longer: `subscribed_at_is_nil` is just one of them. So with your code I need to repeat two times possibly 15 fields or more. And multiple times if I need to conditionally change them again.

Comment: @FredHors in this scenario, are both branches always setting the same fields?

Comment: @kmdreko yep. I have both cases. But the scenario with same fields is the majority.